# nodejs - How to parse the return of connection.query?

Tags: javascript

it's clearly not an array since trying to access it's elements returns undefined.

it's not a nested array either since `result[0].forEach` is not a function.

what exactly is this function returning?

Comment: Add the context of your problem.

Comment: please show the code, where this is coming from... we need context to help

Comment: Please can you provide more details about your problem and share your code please